# Can we, somehow, sticky-mark popular questions to serve as a kind of starting documentation?

Tags: discussion

It surprises me a lot that there are popular questions like these ones:

- [Who wins? I have no clue](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/9814/who-wins-i-have-no-clue)
- [What happens if there is royal flush on board](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/6599/what-happens-if-there-is-royal-flush-on-board)
- [Flush confusion](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/9768/flush-confusion)

Just to name *that* particular topic. With the same emphasis I can recall that, long time ago, I wrote a question/answer of combinatorics and its application to poker, because I found several questions addressing that exact topic with a reduced scope of one particular hand.

Although Poker has a wide range of stuff you could mess with, I see a good quota of repeated questions hanging around, which are appropriately marked as duplicate.

I understand there are cases when a duplicate is useful (to an extent, having many *synonims* for a question is useful), but after reviewing the questions sometimes I'd like to call them to read the manual or, at least, read a kind of source we have in this site.

There is good material here (a notable example written recently by paparazzo) which could serve as a kind of documentation or pinned question/answers here.

Should we (and *can we*) pin content so the users can read them before posting a variant of the same questions? Do we have an equivalent of the StackOverflow's documentation tool here we could use?

Comment: +1 to the question and @herb-wolfe's answer. SE is so standardized though, if it goes on one site, it probably has to go on all the others. In short, youre not just trying to convince Poker.SE users. interesting idea though.

Answer (score 2):

When you go to ask a new question, after typing the title, there are recommendations for similar questions. Unfortunately, I suspect that most posters either ignore those, or don't think they are the same, because the hands are different.